# Line not starting and ending with space

Tags: regex

I need to validate string, which doesn't start or begin with a space.
Spaces within the string are allowed otherwise. What am I doing wrong?

```
^\S*\S$
```

Any space makes the string invalid, it should be only in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: That's equivalent to `^\S+$`: a string consisting of 1 or more non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you meant to write "any string" in the middle. In regex, that's `.*` (0 or more of any char), not `*`:

```
^\S.*\S$
```

Beware: This won't match strings of length 1.

Comment: no need to validate 1 character string. It will be a part of password validator, with minimum 8 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

The *issue* with your expression is that you are not catering for white spaces within your expression.

You would need to change it to `^\S.*\S$` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/dY3jP0/2)).